# How configure OMRON (V750 RFID Reader) via browser-based interface?

Tags: tcpip

I have a [**OMRON V750-series UHF RFID System**](http://www.plceasy.com/Catalog%20Online/pdf/auto_identification_systems/v750.pdf).  I'm trying to access it in a browser via IP address `192.168.1.200`.  However, I can not gain access to it.

Do I need to change my TCP/IP config?

Answer (score 0):

What is the IP of the system you are using to access the Omron device?  If not on the same subnet as 192.168.1.200 then you will have an issue.

If you are not on the same subnet, manually set your IP to something like 192.168.1.100 and subnet 255.255.255.0 Gateway and DNS will not be critical.

Then try to acess